# Compute overlapping time

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, constraint, scheduling

I am trying to solve an optimization problem in which there is a set of tasks, $S$, where $s_i$ and $e_i$ are the starting and ending time of task $i \in S$. Each task $i $ must be done within its time own window $[a_i, b_i]$:
\begin{equation}
a_i \le s_i, \forall i \in S
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
e_i \le b_i, \forall i \in S
\end{equation}

Due to the presence of time windows, tasks could overlap. I have defined continuous variable $t_{ij}$ to quantify the overlapping time of tasks $i$ and $j$.

The objective is to minimize the overlapping time:
\begin{equation}
min \sum_{i,j \in S} t_{ij}
\end{equation}

How can I define constraints to compute $t_{ij}$?

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. Do you have a single resource to process the tasks or there are multiple resources? Is it possible to have no overlap or this is mandatory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that you can omit $t_{ij}$ for any pair $(i,j)$ for which the time windows do not overlap because $t_{ij}=0$ in that case.

Tasks $i$ and $j$ overlap if and only if the later starting time $\max(s_i,s_j)$ precedes the earlier ending time $\min(e_i,e_j)$, so you want to enforce $$t_{ij} \ge \max(\min(e_i,e_j) - \max(s_i,s_j), 0),$$ which can be linearized by introducing
$u_{ij}$ to represent $\max(s_i,s_j)$,
$v_{ij}$ to represent $\min(e_i,e_j)$,
binary variables $x_{ij}$ and $y_{ij}$, and linear constraints:
\begin{align}
0 \le u_{ij} - s_i &\le (b_j-a_i) y_{ij} \tag1\label1\\ 
0 \le u_{ij} - s_j &\le (b_i-a_j) (1-y_{ij}) \tag2\label2\\ 
(a_j-b_i) x_{ij} \le v_{ij} - e_i &\le 0 \tag3\label3\\ 
(a_i-b_j) (1-x_{ij}) \le v_{ij} - e_j &\le 0 \tag4\label4\\ 
t_{ij} &\ge v_{ij} - u_{ij} \tag5\label5 \\ 
t_{ij} &\ge 0 \tag6\label6
\end{align}
Constraints \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} enforce $u_{ij}=\max(s_i,s_j)$.
Constraints \eqref{3} and \eqref{4} enforce $v_{ij}=\min(e_i,e_j)$.
Constraints \eqref{5} and \eqref{6} enforce $t_{ij}\ge\max(v_{ij}-u_{ij},0)$.

Comment: Does this require the introduction of binary variables?

Comment: @prubin Yes, it does.

Comment: @RobPratt thank you very much for your help. It works perfectly :)